# why is onClick() triggered twice when rending the buttons using map()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to frontend and I am trying to implement a simple feature where:
retrieve a list of cities, render a button for each city and catch the click action of them individually

I am getting the list like this:

```
this.state.favCts: ['Sydney', 'melbourne', 'tokyo', 'bankok']
```

and rendering the buttons like this

```
<div className="column">
                    {this.state.favCts.map(
                        (item, index) => 
                             <button key={index} onClick = {console.log("show fav city" + item)}>{item}</button>
                    )}
</div>
```

however the buttons will be clicked twice when they are being rendered, and won't log anything if I click them afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this changes:
`<button key={index} onClick={() => console.log("show fav city" + item)}>{item}</button>`